Transition and animation between a full screen div in fixed positon, to a relative positon
I need a div, which at the beginning, should take the whole viewport. After a delay, this div has to change to a relative position and change its dimensions to fit the width and a 16/9 ratio. The transition has to be animated, not instant.
I tried by adding a class after a delay, but it doesn't make it animated...
setTimeout(function() {
  var deckContainers = document.querySelectorAll('div.deck-container');
  deckContainers.forEach(function(deckContainer) {
    deckContainer.classList.toggle('collapsed');
  });
}, 800);

.deck-container {
  background-color: red;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;  
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: fixed;
}

.deck-container.collapsed {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

https://jsfiddle.net/LaitEau/feo78wyg/
https://jsfiddle.net/LaitEau/n2swL6k3/1/
Any idea about the direction I should take?
Here is a gif of a prototype of the behavior I'm trying to make : https://i.ibb.co/6R2mtYF/Untitled.gif

position cannot be animated or transitioned.

@Paulie_D It can not between two types of "position" but can with one like here ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620269/5187225

Here is a .gif of a prototype : https://i.ibb.co/6R2mtYF/Untitled.gif

Something like this? Then you should target the body margin and its transition.
https://jsfiddle.net/to6c21ew/2/


setTimeout(function() {
  var deckContainers = document.querySelectorAll('div.deck-container');
  deckContainers.forEach(function(deckContainer) {
    deckContainer.classList.toggle('collapsed');
  });
}, 1300);

setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.style.margin = '16px';
}, 1300);
body {
  margin: 0px;
  transition: margin 1s;
}

div.deck-container {
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
}

div.deck-container.collapsed {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div400px {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
}

.div100px {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
<div class="div100px"></div>
<div class="deck-container"></div>
<div class="div400px"></div>




More something like this : https://i.ibb.co/6R2mtYF/Untitled.gif
